# How to pivot a pandas Dataframe to a new Dataframe instead of a Dataseries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with 4 columns: Mes (month), Clientes (clients), Mercadorias (Assets) and Quantidade (quantity) and I'm trying to create a new dataframe grouping by the columns month and clients running the following code: `data = df.groupby(['Mes','Clientes'])['Quantidade'].sum()`

The output values are ok however it is creating a **pandas.core.series.Series** and wish to create a **pandas.core.frame.DataFrame**

Could someone please help me?

Comment: Could you please add sample data? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: `data = df.groupby(['Mes','Clientes'])['Quantidade'].sum().reset_index()` should do what you ask for

Comment: @anky, thanks! now I can see it as a Dataframe.